CSS and script files not loading on Express app, giving net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
I have an express backend server. It has to render EJS page with index.js in it when it launches.
However, I get 3 errors:

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/styles/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
GET http://localhost:3000/public/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/public/index.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Root directory contains:

'node_modules' folder
'public' folder that contains: - 'images' folder
- 'styles' folder that contains: 'style.css' file
- index.js file
'views' folder that contains: - 'partials' folder that contains: - footer.ejs file
- header.ejs file
- create.ejs file
- home.ejs file
- view.ejs file
package-lock.json
package.json

Inside footer.ejs I have the following line:   <script src="public/index.js"></script>
Inside header.ejs I have the following line:   <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/styles/style.css">
Inside index.js I have the following lines:
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname, join } from 'path';

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)); // Define __dirname using import.meta.url

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Set the 'views' directory for Express to find the EJS templates
app.set('views', join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));

// Configure Express to use EJS as the template engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Serve static files from the 'public' directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// Parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Also, I have a problem with a Bootstrap Hamburger menu that doesn't work when it's in the small version.
This is the code in the header.ejs for the NavBar:
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md bg-body-tertiary border-bottom" data-bs-theme="dark" >
        <div class="container-fluid">
       <a class="navbar-brand">Luk's Blog</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
           <div class="navbar-nav">
           <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
           <a class="nav-link" href="/create">Write Blog</a>
           </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</nav> 

Does it need to be defined in JS for it to work?
I checked the path for the files, the spelling, I even used chatgpt to search for the issue and we go in circles with no result.
Also, please note that if I run the server locally, the functions defined in the index.js are working (even if I got the errors shown above), the only problem is with the CSS files (not loading)

You need to omit public from src attribute of resources in EJS templates, because:

Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the
name of the static directory is not part of the URL.
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

so change
<script src="public/index.js"></script>

to
<script src="index.js"></script>

etc.
You can define any mount path, so it would work if you add public as a path:
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

and now it would load with 'public`:
<script src="public/index.js"></script>

As to the Bootstrap navbar, make sure you load Bootstrap resources (only once, on index.ejs, not in partials), it runs via data-bs-toggle attributes automatically:
BS navbar


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example m-0 border-0">

    <!-- Example Code -->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md bg-body-tertiary border-bottom" data-bs-theme="dark" >
        <div class="container-fluid">
       <a class="navbar-brand">Luk's Blog</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
           <div class="navbar-nav">
           <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
           <a class="nav-link" href="/create">Write Blog</a>
           </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</nav> 
    
      
    <!-- End Example Code -->
  </body>
</html>



and also make sure your custom styles do not collide somehow.

Hi there @traynor! I appreciate your response.
I have removed 'public' from my script src to 'index.js' and from my href link to CSS and I get the same errors. I have even tried it with the mount path defined with 'public' and it's not working.
I have changed the href from my CSS to src and I don't get the error regarding the CSS, but the styles are not applied.
However, I have managed to resolve the hamburger menu issue thanks to you.
Cheers!

in main template (presumably index.ejs), in head, try adding <base href="/" target="_blank">

there is no index.ejs. I tried adding this in the head but nothing changed

can't reproduce. try moving script tag into main template, try with just bare view just to make sure public resources are loading, then try moving them to partials. you could also include view, partial, and a route where this happens, i.e. reproducible code
